# Instalé Visual Studio para C#, pero no instalé ninguna herramienta de ".net", lo puedo instalar aparte, descargando el sdk de .net?

Tags: c#, .net, visual, studio

No tiene ningún componente de ".net"

Comment: visual studio es una ide que podes instalar con los paquetes que necesites.. volve a ejecutar el instalador, modifica la instalacion y agrega los paquetes con los que vas a trabajar. la respuesta ademas es si.

Comment: Gracias por contestar, tengo el sdk .net, pero no sé si debería instalar dentro de la carpeta donde sé instaló Visual Studio.

Comment: El sdk se instala solo sobre el sistema operativo. Pero no tenes que instalar eso. Si instalas visual con las herramientas que queres usar, se va a encargar de instalar todo...

Comment: Ok gracias @gbianchi por contestar y aclararme ese tema, ahora los instaló directamente desde el visual...

Comment: Si, podes descargar los SDK aparte pero si o si necesitas las cargas de trabajo de Visual Studio para poder programar en C#

Comment: Si, así parece. Igual desinstale el que tenía y descargué el Visual Studio conmunity 2017, e instalé el .net desde el propio instalador del visual. Gracias por la info igual...